# sw-precache: Deleted cache, FetchEvent error response

Tags: javascript, caching, service-worker, sw-precache

I am using sw-precache for adding offline support to a web app.

My setup:

1. Static website with CSS/JS/HTML Dynamic content is handled via
   custom indexedDB solution.
2. Grunt task used generate the service-worker.
3. sw-precache (4.0.0) used to cache ALL the static
   assets.
4. cache headers on service-worker.js set on apache as
   follows:

> ```
> <LocationMatch "service-worker\.js.*">
>     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache"
> </LocationMatch>
> ```

Things seem to work fine in usual cases. But if for some reason, the user clears the cache (e.g In chrome dev tools -> Applications -> Clear Storage  (Select everything) -> click 'clear selected'), my web pages don't load **even If I am online** and I see following error in console:

The FetchEvent for "https://my.somedomain.com/somepath/somepage.html" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith().

When I look at the generated service-worker.js, I notice the following code.

```
// If shouldRespond was set to true at any point, then call
// event.respondWith(), using the appropriate cache key.
if (shouldRespond) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(urlsToCacheKeys.get(url));
    }).catch(function(e) {
      // Fall back to just fetch()ing the request if some unexpected error
      // prevented the cached response from being valid.
      console.warn('Couldn\'t serve response for "%s" from cache: %O', event.request.url, e);
      return fetch(event.request);
    })
  );
```

When debugging, I don't see the catch block getting executed. Also see the attached debug output of the object returned catch.match that is passed to respondWith()
[image: Console debug output of promise object passed to respondWith]

So my questions:

1. Why does sw-precache not fallback to network when it does not find the entry in cache?
2. Is there anyway to force network request when a request entry is not found in cache?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this should be reported via the `sw-precache` issue tracker. I've moved it to https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues/185

Comment: For future reference, this is a bug that will be fixed with https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/pull/186

Comment: @JeffPosnick Thanks for reporting in sw-precache. Normally I have seen module owners asking users to use forums for questions/issues rather than the issue tracker. Hence the post. I will followup in tracker. Thanks again!

Comment: In this case it was an actual bug, so having a record of it in the `sw-precache` issue tracker was important.